# How to execute perl tests located in several files?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, junit

Why following code executes tests from check2.t file only?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Modern::Perl;

use TAP::Harness::JUnit;

my $harness = TAP::Harness::JUnit->new({
   xmlfile => 'output.xml',
   namemangle => 'hudson',
   merge => 1
});

$harness->runtests(['check1.t', 'check2.t']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it runs the tests from `check1.t` while calling it `check2.t`.  As davorg pointed out, `runtests` expects a list of tests, not an arrayref of tests.  The reason why it appears to work is that `runtests` also allows a test entry to be in the form `[ 'filename', 'comment' ]`, where `filename` is the name of the test file, and `comment` is the string to display.  (This is [documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TAP%3a%3aHarness#runtests) in the base class, [TAP::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TAP%3a%3aHarness).)

Answer (score 0):

Does it even run tests from check2.t? The [documentation for the module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Harness-JUnit/lib/TAP/Harness/JUnit.pm) says that runtests takes a list of test files, not an array reference. Try changing the runtests line to:

```
$harness->runtests('check1.t', 'check2.t');
```